# use a table instead of switch case in C

Tags: arrays, c, switch-statement

How to replace switch case by a table in this case, please?

```
typedef enum
{   DIV_1 = 1,
    DIV_2,
    DIV_4 = 4,
    DIV_8 = 8,
    DIV_16 = 16
} eDiv_t;

eDiv_t Division;

uint32_t dividerValue;

    switch (Division)
    {

        case DIV_1:
            dividerValue = RCC_DIV_1;
        break;
        case DIV_2:
            dividerValue = RCC_DIV_2;
        break;
        case DIV_4:
            dividerValue = RCC_DIV_4;
        break;
        case DIV_8:
            dividerValue = RCC_DIV_8;
        break;
        case DIV_16:
            dividerValue = RCC_DIV_16;
        break;
        default:
            dividerValue = RCC_DIV_1;
        break;
    }
```

I don't know how to affect enum variables to an array and use it instead of switch case

Comment: The compiler will probably compile the code as a lookup table. You can do `uint32_t table[17] = { 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 16};` and, assuming `Division` is between `0` and `16`: `dividerValue = table[Division];`

Comment: but I only have 5 variables, if I allocate 17 cases of an array without using most of them won't that affect performance?

Comment: Make the array `static`. But, **no**, without measurements nothing you do affects performance. And if you measure, you will find better ways to optimize than here. Remember: *premature optimization is the root of all evil*

Comment: Why is the enum not using values from 0, 1, 2 and upwards? Do you use it for some other purpose than this switch?

Comment: @YosraMH Apart from general optimization advice: Making arrays larger as such will never affect performance (well, unless you exceed cache size). Initializing large chunks of memory will; but 16 elements is not large, and as pmg said, if you make it static it will be initialized once, at startup or compile time, so it doesn't have a run time overhead. If you can replace jumps (like if/else or switches) with computations or lookups it is almost always faster to do so. At run time, *jumps* kill performance.

Comment: @Lundin yes it's used in other location too and it's a division by either 1 or 2 or 4 or 8 or 16. 
before transforming it to enum, I wrote it as #define but then I think enum is better than putting too much #define at user side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define your enum as consecutive integer values and index your array with this enum:

```
typedef enum
{   DIV_1 = 0,
    DIV_2,
    DIV_4,
    DIV_8,
    DIV_16,
    NB_DIV
} eDiv_t;

unsigned int dividerValue[NB_DIV] = {RCC_DIV1, RCC_DIV2, ..., RCC_DIV16};
```

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case where `eDiv_t` can't be changed because it is used elsewhere, a lookup table can be made as:

```
RCC_t eDiv_to_RCC (eDiv_t ediv)
{
  static const RCC_t lookup [16+1] = 
  {
    [DIV_1]  = RCC_DIV1,
    [DIV_2]  = RCC_DIV2,
    [DIV_4]  = RCC_DIV4,
    [DIV_8]  = RCC_DIV8,
    [DIV_16] = RCC_DIV16,
  };

  return lookup[ediv];  // returns 0 if invalid input
}
```

This is very fast but consumes `17 *  sizeof(RCC_t)` which I assume is another enum, likely 8 to 32 bits large. Not that big, but this is an execution speed over .rodata size optimization. On the other hand the actual code will take much less space than the switch version.